# SQLAlchemy - create table from yaml or a dictionary?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, yaml

Is there a way to create a dynamic table from a dictionary specified in a yaml file? I define a lot of the ETL config in the yaml file, so I was curious if I could also add the table creation aspect to it as well so I do not have to modify a separate .sql file in a separate directory.

```
database:
  table: 'schema.fact_stuff'
  create_columns: [
    {}
  ] #not sure how this section should be
```

I found a solution on stackoverflow which zipped some lists together which is something similar, but I would prefer to define each column explicitly.

```
{'column_name': 'id', 'column_type': Integer, 'primary_key': False, 'nullable': True}
```

I ended up getting it to work with this:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import (Integer, NUMERIC, TEXT, BOOLEAN, TIMESTAMP, DATE)

sql_types = {'integer': Integer,
        'numeric': NUMERIC,
        'text': TEXT,
        'date': DATE,
        'timestamp': TIMESTAMP(timezone=False),
        'timestamptz': TIMESTAMP(timezone=True)}

exclude_list = ['original_name']
table_dict = [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in exclude_list} for d in c[variable]['load']['columns']]
for column in table_dict:
    for key, val in column.copy().items():
        if key == 'type_':
            column[key] = sql_types[val]
        elif key == 'default':
            column[key] = dt.datetime.utcnow

metadata = sa.MetaData(schema=c[variable]['load']['schema'])
metadata.reflect(bind=engine, autoload=True)
fact = sa.Table(c[variable]['load']['table'], metadata, extend_existing=True,
        *(sa.Column(**kwargs) for kwargs in table_dict))
fact.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)
```

But then I moved over to having pandas determine the dtypes instead of defining them in a yaml file. This creates the sql with a jinja2 template and I loop through all of my data sources to create the DDL.

```
def pandas_to_postgres(df):
    dtype_dict = {
      'i': 'integer',
      'O': 'text',
      'f': 'real',
      'b': 'boolean',
      'datetime64[ns]': 'timestamp',
      'datetime64[ns, UTC]': 'timestampz',
    }
    column_list = []
    column_dict = {}
    for k, v in df.dtypes.items():
        column_dict['name'] = k
        column_dict['dtype'] = dtype_dict.get(v.kind, 'text')
        column_list.append(column_dict.copy())
    return column_list


def generate_create_table(df, schema, table, table_type, columns, constraint, unique_columns):
    """ Returns a dictionary of coefs from training """
    query = Template(
        template
    ).render(
        schema_name=schema,
        table_name=table,
        table_type=table_type,
        columns=columns,
        constraint=constraint,
        constraint_columns=unique_columns
    )
    print(query)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today's release of **SQLAthanor** (v.0.3.0) supports exactly that. Using **SQLAthanor**, you can programmatically generate a SQLAlchemy `Table` object with the following code (assuming `metadata` contains your SQLAlchemy `MetaData` object):

```
from sqlathanor import Table

my_table = Table.from_yaml('yaml_file.yaml', 
                           'my_table_name', 
                           metadata, 
                           primary_key = 'id')
```

**ETA:** Note that you can also create `Table` objects using `Table.from_json()`, `Table.from_dict()`, and `Table.from_csv()` as well.

Here's the documentation (generally) for how it works: https://sqlathanor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#generating-sqlalchemy-tables-from-serialized-data

And here's a link to the documentation of the specific `Table.from_yaml()` method: https://sqlathanor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#sqlathanor.schema.Table.from_yaml

(I recommend reviewing the method documentation - it goes into some of the "gotcha's" of programmatically constructing a `Table` object from serialized data)

---

**ETA:**

Basically, the way programmatic `Table` generation works is that SQLAthanor:

1. First converts a serialized string (or file) into a Python `dict`. For YAML, the default de-serializer is [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation). For JSON, the default de-serializer is [simplejson](https://simplejson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (both default deserializers can be overriden using the `deserialize_function` argument).
2. Once a Python `dict` has been generated, SQLAthanor reads each of the keys in that `dict` to determine the column names. It reads the values for each key, and based on the data type of the value tries to "guess" at the SQLAlchemy data type.
3. Given what it found in step 2, it creates a `Table` object with `Column` objects where each `Column` object corresponds to a key in the de-serialized `dict`.

If you need more precise control over each `Column`, you can:

- override its SQLAlchemy data type using the `type_mapping` argument (`type_mapping` receives a `dict` where top-level keys correspond to a column name, and each value is the data type to apply to the `Column`)
- pass additional keyword arguments to the `Column` constructor using the `column_kwargs` argument (`column_kwargs` receives a `dict` where top-level keys corresponds to the column name, and each value is a `dict` with keyword arguments that will be supplied to that column's constructor.

By default, `Table.from_<format>()` does *not* support nested data structures. By default, `skip_nested` is set to `True`, which means that a key in the de-serialized `dict` that contains a nested object (either an iterable or a `dict`) will be skipped (i.e. won't receive a corresponding `Column`). If your `Table` needs to store nested data, you can set `skip_nested` to `False` and activate `default_to_str` to `True`. This will convert nested data (iterables or `dict` objects) to strings and thus persist them in a `Text` column (unless overridden by `type_mapping`).

---

**`Table.from_dict()` example**

The following is an example `dict` that can be supplied to `Table.from_dict()`:

```
sample_dict = {
    'id': 123,
    'some_column_name': 'Some Column Value',
    'created_datetime': datetime.utcnow()
}

my_table = Table.from_dict(sample_dict, 
                           'my_table', 
                           metadata, 
                           primary_key = 'id')
```

When supplied to `Table.from_dict()` this `dict` will produce a `Table` object with database table name `my_table` that contains three columns:

- `id` which will have type `Integer` that is set to be the table's primary key
- `some_column_name` which will have type `Text`
- `created_datetime` which will have type `DateTime`

**`Table.from_yaml()` example**

The following is the same example, but using a YAML string/document instead that can be supplied to `Table.from_yaml()`:

```
sample_yaml = """
    id: 123
    some_column_name: Test Value
    created_timestamp: 2018-01-01T01:23:45.67890
"""

my_table = Table.from_yaml(sample_yaml, 
                           'my_table', 
                           metadata, 
                           primary_key = 'id')
```

When supplied to `Table.from_yaml()` this will first de-serialize `sample_yaml` into a `dict` just like in the earlier example, and then produce a `Table` object with database table name `my_table` that contains three columns:

- `id` which will have type `Integer` that is set to be the table's primary key
- `some_column_name` which will have type `Text`
- `created_datetime` which will have type `DateTime`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow nice, yeah I just edited my question and included some of the paths I went down. Do you have an example of the yaml file or dict which would be used as the input? I am currently using pandas with df.columns and df.types and passing it to a jinja template because it was tedious updating a yaml file by hand.

Comment: No worries! I updated my answer with a more detailed explanation, including an example of using `Table.from_dict()` and `Table.from_yaml()` with a Python `dict` and corresponding YAML document. Hope it helps clarify!

Comment: perfect, that clears it up for me. thanks a bunch. going to give this a shot

Comment: Wow! Your library looks very cool! Do you have some examples of YAML/JSON files with table definitions (including constraints [primary, unique, not null, etc.])?

Comment: Some of the [docs](https://sqlathanor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#generating-sqlalchemy-tables-from-serialized-data) include setting primary keys via the `primary_key` argument. However, I recommend the actual [Table.from_*() docs](https://sqlathanor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#sqlathanor.schema.Table.from_json) which lets you set `Column` constraints by passing in a `dict` of columns and their  keyword arguments to the `column_kwargs` argument which gets passed to SQLAlchemy. So to make "notNullColumn" NOT NULL, you would pass `{ 'notNullColumn': { 'nullable': False } }`

Comment: Also, to be clear about one thing: the JSON/YAML files themselves do not define the constraints: Those get defined in the Python call to the `Table.from_json()` or similar method. I've got a [feature request](https://github.com/insightindustry/sqlathanor/issues/55) to serialization to leverage JSON Schema and OpenAPI which may extend some of the "constraint setting" functionality, but it's not supported quite yet.

Comment: I'm still trying to find any JSON or YAML table definition example which could be used together with the `new_from_yaml()` method. Do you have any sample files and code snippets for any of `new_from_*()` methods?

Comment: @MaxU: Are you trying to create a `Table` from YAML or are you trying to create an ORM `BaseModel`? The SO post we’re commenting on has examples of the first, while examples of the second are available [here](https://sqlathanor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#id13) (you can use the same YAML snippets listed here as your `yaml_string` values). Once you have your ORM models generated, you can call `.new_from_yaml()` on them with your YAML, as is shown with a bunch of examples in the docs. The GH code has some test JSON files in the `tests/input_files/JSON` folder you can play with, too.

Comment: Since SO comments are limited in terms of their length and formatting, feel free to post an actual SO question or post a question to the SQLAthanor [Issues](https://github.com/insightindustry/sqlathanor/issues) list - happy to give a more comprehensive answer if you’d find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me and came here because you just wanted to just create multiple table structures from a JSON or dict and not necessarily append any data to it.

I achieved it using sqlalchemy.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, String

# Example 'diff_tables' dictionary structure
diff_tables = {
    "table_name1": ["column1", "column2"],
    "table_name2": ["column1", "column2", "column3"],
}

conn = create_engine("postgresql://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}")

metadata = MetaData(schema='schema_name')

for table_name, columns in diff_tables.items():
    table_columns = [Column(column_name, String) for column_name in columns]
    table = Table(table_name, metadata, *table_columns)
    table.create(conn)

print("Tables created successfully!")
```